# Can I apply tf.map_fn(...) to multiple inputs/outputs?

Tags: tensorflow

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = tf.constant([True, False], dtype=tf.bool)

a.eval()
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
b.eval()
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I want to apply a functions to the inputs above, `a`, and `b` using `tf.map_fn`. It will input both `[1,2,3]`, and `True` and output similar values.

Let's say out function is simply the identity: `lambda(x,y): x,y` so, given an input of `[1,2,3], True`, it will output those identical tensors.

I know how to use `tf.map_fn(...)` with one variable, but not with two. And in this case I have mixed data types (int32 and bool) so I can't simply concatenate the tensors and split them after the call.

Can I use `tf.map_fn(...)` with multiple inputs/outputs of different data types?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to define the data types for each tensor in `dtype` for each of the different tensors, then you can pass the tensors as a tuple, your map function receives a tuple of inputs, and `map_fn` returns back back a tuple.

Example that works:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = tf.constant([True, False], dtype=tf.bool)

c = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), (a,b), dtype=(tf.int32, tf.bool))

c[0].eval()
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
c[1].eval()
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Be warned that if you use this the processing will be done in CPU, not on the GPU. This can be especially detrimental to speed when training on a GPU.

Comment: How do you know that this particular function uses the CPU instead of the GPU? Is it due to the function tf.map_fn itself or the dtype specification?

Comment: Revisiting this a couple of years later, I'm not so sure about that comment. If lambda only returns TF ops, I'm not sure if those will drop to the CPU or not, and I'm not sure if anything's changed in TF between then and now. If someone wants to confirm with a trace or dump of what devices the tensors are attached to that would be useful. It seems that if `fn` returns TF ops only, those should operate on the default device.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for TFv2

Given

```py
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=tf.int32)
b = tf.constant([True, False], dtype=tf.bool)
```

The `fn` should only take 1 arg but you can pass a tuple of `tf.Tensor` to your function and then split them inside the function like

```py
def fn(a_and_b):
    a, b = a_and_b
    # then do more stuff on a and b
    return (a, b)
```

Then call `tf.map_fn` by

```py
c = tf.map_fn(
    fn,
    elems=(a, b),
    fn_output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[3], dtype=tf.int32), 
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.bool), 
    ),
)
```

This gives

```py
>>> c
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True, False])>)
```

Note `dtype` argument is deprecated for [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn).

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are a little messy, you can define the stack "type" explicitly with a custom [Extension Type](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extension_type). Here's your example in a hopefully more readable form:

```py
class BoolAndVector(tf.experimental.BatchableExtensionType):
    """A collection bools and vectors."""
    bool: tf.Tensor
    vector: tf.Tensor

@tf.function
def fn(bool_and_vector):
   return BoolAndVector(bool=bool_and_vector.bool,
                         vector=[bool_and_vector.vector[0]])

c = tf.map_fn(fn, BoolAndVector(bool=b, vector=a))
```

You might have to explicitly state the signature type, but the errors will guide you to what TF wants.

Note, you'll need to use [BatchableExtensionType](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/BatchableExtensionType) to make this usable with map.

Answer (score -1):

Do what is said below, but tuple unpack the values inside the `tf.function` without the lambda, as computationally expensive and lambdas do not work well with TensorFlow as tf functions.

```
@tf.function
def x(x):
  x,y = tuple(x) 
  return 

c = tf.map_fn(, (a,b), dtype=(tf.int32, tf.bool))
```