# How to use tensor as a input of a function?(tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to use tensorflow to construct my model to solve a differential equations, for example,

```
dX/dt=f(\mu,X,t)
```

Here, \mu is a function depends on X, which is complex so that I want to predict \mu(X) using neural net.

First, my input, X, passes a dense layer N to get \mu~N(X).
Then, I solve the ODE above using Runge-Kutta method, which is defined by a code:

```
def RK4(self, mu, X, t, dt=0.2):
    kX1=dt*self.f(mu, X, t)
    kX2=dt*self.f(mu, X+kX1/2, t+dt/2)
    kX3=dt*self.f(mu, X+kX2/2, t+dt/2)
    kX4=dt*self.f(mu, X+kX3, t+dt)
    X_next=X+(kX1+2*kX2+2*kX3+kX4)/6

    return X_next
```

Note that self comes from a class variable.
When I directly put N(X) into RK4, an error occurs.

```
 Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate 
 over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

I'm not familiar with this map_fn. My function is complicated because it has both tensor(\mu, X) and float(t, dt). But as I know, map_fn only deals with a tensor input. Is there a smart way to deals with these inputs? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more code and toy example?

Comment: Sure, I editted my problem with details

Comment: If you want to insert N directly, would it help to solve X'=g(X,t) with RK4 where g is defined as `g=lambda X,t: f(N(X),X,t)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X_next= tf.map_fn(lambda x : self.RK4(x[0],x[1],x[2]),(self.mu, self.X, self.t), dtype=tf.float32)
```

will solve my problem. In fact, tf.map_fn can receive either tensor type inputs or float type inputs. Usage of such a function can be seen from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892347/can-i-apply-tf-map-fn-to-multiple-inputs-outputs)